# A simple HTTPS proxy server with Apache Camel

Tags: java, https, apache-camel, http-proxy

I am trying to implement a simple HTTP proxy service with Apache Camel.
My code looks like this:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:80?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.recipientList(simple("jetty:${in.header.CamelHttpUrl}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false&disableStreamCache=true"));
```

It is essentially [this](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html) with a dynamic recipient list to support multiple destinations. I also had to add the `disableStreamCache=true` bit, otherwise I would get weird exceptions with path duplication (like `/index.html` would become `/index.html/index.html`).

Nevertheless, it seems to work. But only with HTTP requests. When I try accessing an HTTPS site, I always get a 404.

According to the logs, the jetty component just doesn't seem to find the remote server. I have no idea why.

```
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST www.google.cz:443 on AsyncHttpConnection@6964b063,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=17,c=0},r=1
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - scope null||www.google.cz:443 @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - context=null||www.google.cz:443 @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - servlet null||www.google.cz:443 -> null
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=null
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - Not Found www.google.cz:443
01:36:37.495 [qtp85415531-22 - www.google.cz:443] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE www.google.cz:443  200 handled=false
```

What should I do to enable this HTTPS support? Is it even possible with standard Camel components?

**Edit:**

I managed to update my route definition to not use a recipient list. I don't know whether this improves anything performance-wise (does it?) but it feels better. I was also able to remove the path duplication problem when not using `disableStreamCache=true` by this.

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:80?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http4:dummy?bridgeEndpoint=true&urlRewrite=#urlRewrite&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

And the URL rewriter implementation:

```
UrlRewrite urlRewrite = new HttpServletUrlRewrite() {
    @Override
    public String rewrite(String url, String relativeUrl, Producer producer, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        return request.getRequestURL().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String rewrite(String url, String relativeUrl, Producer producer) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
};
```

**Edit 2:**

I should probably mention that I would like to intercept those requests and read/alter content (actually only HTTP headers). In effect I would like to implement an MITM proxy.

**Edit 3:**

I tried replacing the target component with `log` to see whether the request gets through:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:80?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("log:test")
```

The message gets logged when used as a proxy with HTTP. It also gets logged when I replace the URI with `jetty:https://localhost?matchOnUriPrefix=true` and try opening `https://localhost` directly in the browser. However, when trying to use this as a proxy with HTTPS, I cannot get it to log. It seems like the Jetty component doesn't support this behavior. Is it correct?

I also tried using the Netty-http component with similar results (route tracer logged the `CONNECT` request but the message doesn't get passed to the Log component)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key was to define a handler for jetty that would take care of the `CONNECT` method:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:80?matchOnUriPrefix=true&handlers=#connectHandler")
```

The `connectHandler` in this case can be either a Jetty `ConnectHandler` (for normal HTTPS proxies) or a custom one (for MITM proxies):

```
class CustomConnectHandler extends ConnectHandler {
    @Override
    protected SocketChannel connect(HttpServletRequest request, String host, int port) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = SocketChannel.open();
        channel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
        channel.socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 443), getConnectTimeout());
        return channel;
    }
}
```

This one connects to port 443 on the localhost and routes SSL data there. So we need to define another route from there:

```
from("jetty:https://localhost:443?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
```

(we can keep two separate routes or join them later by using a SEDA component)

To define custom SSL context parameters (key store, trust store, etc.), we can use the `sslContextParametersRef` parameter on the endpoint.

Next, we need to alter the URL. We do this by populating the URI header with the full URL (it's only the relative path by default):

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("${header.CamelHttpUrl}"))
```

We also need to remove the PATH header because the HTTP4 component builds the final URL by concatenating the URI and PATH headers:

```
.removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
```

Finally, we can forward the message to the HTTP4 component. We should also set `throwExceptionOnFailure=false` to forward errors to the client and `httpClient.redirectsEnabled=false` to forward redirects (this can otherwise mess with some sites):

```
.to("http4:dummy?throwExceptionOnFailure=false&httpClient.redirectsEnabled=false");
```

I hope this helps anyone who is looking to implement an HTTPS proxy using Camel and was struggling like me.

Answer (score 0):

On most computer systems, localhost resolves to the IP address 127.0.0.1

Note:- This is a valid implementation in case of using Fiddler.***

```
<camelContext id="context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <properties>
        <property key="http.proxyHost" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <property key="http.proxyPort" value="8888"/>
   </properties>
</camelContext>
```